# How do you sign a HIPAA BAA for Google Cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hipaa

Not sure if this question is appropriate for this topic.

There is a lot of documentation stating that Google will sign a BAA for their services but it is very difficult to find the place to actually sign it. After a few searches I was able to find how to sign a BAA for AWS. I'd prefer to use GCP since it's the platform I'm familiar with but I may need to switch to AWS if I can't sign a BAA with Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This page details Google Cloud HIPAA Compliance. You will need to contact your account manager to receive a BAA. Also required is that you do not use / disable any products not covered by the BAA.

https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/

[Update Nov-26-2018]

If you have setup G Suite:

Login to [G Suite](https://admin.google.com) as an admin.

Go to Company profile -> Profile -> Security and Privacy Additional Terms.

You will find `G Suite/Cloud Identity HIPAA Business Associate Amendment`.

Comment: If my account is not large enough to have an account manager am I just out of luck?

Comment: Contact Google Support. They can get you in touch with someone.

Comment: I don't have this option in my G Suite. What to do?

Comment: For Google Workspace, you can accept the agreement from you admin console at: https://admin.google.com/ac/companyprofile/legal (Security and Privacy Additional Terms)